# Changing variable names with Python for loops

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

I was just wondering if anyone knew of a way to change variable names based off of a for loop for something like this:

```
for i in range(3)
     group+i=self.getGroup(selected, header+i)
```

so that the names of the variables change to accomodate the data.  Thanks!

~Sam

Comment: What would the point of changing the variable name be?

Answer (score 70):

You probably want a dict instead of separate variables.  For example

```
d = {}
for i in range(3):
    d["group" + str(i)] = self.getGroup(selected, header+i)
```

If you insist on actually modifying local variables, you could use the `locals` function:

```
for i in range(3):
    locals()["group"+str(i)] = self.getGroup(selected, header+i)
```

On the other hand, if what you actually want is to modify instance variables of the class you're in, then you can use the `setattr` function

```
for i in group(3):
    setattr(self, "group"+str(i), self.getGroup(selected, header+i)
```

And of course, I'm assuming with all of these examples that you don't just want a list:

```
groups = [self.getGroup(i,header+i) for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: what if the range is unknown, how can I approach this problem?

Comment: @EmmanuelManoloSiame you can use the `len()` method in Python. Read more about the len() method [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/len).

Answer (score 11):

Use a list.

```
groups = [0]*3
for i in xrange(3):
    groups[i] = self.getGroup(selected, header + i)
```

or more "Pythonically":

```
groups = [self.getGroup(selected, header + i) for i in xrange(3)]
```

For what it's worth, you *could* try to create variables the "wrong" way, i.e. by modifying the dictionary which holds their values:

```
l = locals()
for i in xrange(3):
    l['group' + str(i)] = self.getGroup(selected, header + i)
```

but that's really bad form, and possibly not even guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 6):

Definitely should use a dict using the  "group" + str(i) key as described in the accepted solution but I wanted to share a solution using exec. Its a way to parse strings into commands & execute them dynamically. It would allow to create these scalar variable names as per your requirement instead of using a dict. This might help in regards what not to do, and just because you can doesn't mean you should. Its a good solution only if using scalar variables is a hard requirement:

```
l = locals()
for i in xrange(3):
    exec("group" + str(i) + "= self.getGroup(selected, header + i)")
```

Another example where this could work using a Django model example. The exec alternative solution is commented out and the better way of handling such a case using the **dict** attribute makes more sense:

```
Class A(models.Model):

    ....

    def __getitem__(self, item):  # a.__getitem__('id')
        #exec("attrb = self." + item)
        #return attrb
        return self.__dict__[item]
```

It might make more sense to extend from a dictionary in the first place to get setattr and getattr functions.

A situation which involves parsing, for example generating & executing python commands  dynamically, exec is what you want :) More on exec [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to use a list instead:

```
group=[]
for i in range(3):
     group[i]=self.getGroup(selected, header+i)
```

Comment: Do you mean "Dictionary" or "List"?  What's an Array?

Comment: I mean List, thanks. I've called ordered collections of items "arrays" for a very long time, and have never used PHP where they usurped the term to mean "associative array".

Answer (score -1):

You *could* access your class's `__dict__` attribute:

```
for i in range(3)
     self.__dict__['group%d' % i]=self.getGroup(selected, header+i)
```

But why can't you just use an array named `group`?

Comment: Instead of using self.__dict__[etc] you'll want to use setattr(self, etc), and I'm sure you meant to say 'list' instead of 'array'.  Good use of string formatting though.