# Iterating through a list of Form Objects with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing variable names with Python for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060090/changing-variable-names-with-python-for-loops)

I have created a form that has 24 line edit boxes (objects) in it.  I want to update an attribute on each object based upon data entered by the user (I want to enable or disable the line edit box).

So I am trying to do something like:

```
    if self.cmbSelectDevice.currentText() == 'Adtran 904' :
        for EnableLine in range(1,  5) :
            self.lblFxsLine'EnableLine'.setEnabled(1)
        for DisableLine in range (6, 24) :
            self.lblFxsLine'DisableLine'.setEnabled(0)
```

'EnableLine' and 'DisableLine' are the values I am trying to substitute.  If I did this all manually it woudl look something like:

```
    if self.cmbSelectDevice.currentText() == 'Adtran 904' :
        self.lblFxsLine1.setEnabled(1)
        self.lblFxsLine2.setEnabled(1)
        self.lblFxsLine3.setEnabled(1)
        etc...
        self.lblFxsLine6.setEnabled(0)
        self.lblFxsLine7.setEnabled(0)
        etc...
```

List and dictionaries don't really work here since I am trying to manipulate attributes on objects in a form (at least I think they don't, I am really new to python).

Any help/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to create these forms? PyGTK? PyQt? Tkinter? Or is it web?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothin preventing you from putting your `lblFxsLine` into a dictionary or list.

```
self.lblFxsLines = [lblFxsLine for i in range(1,25)]

...

if self.cmbSelectDevice.currentText() == 'Adtran 904' :
    for enableLine in range(1,  5) :
        self.lblFxsLines[enableLine].setEnabled(1)
    for disableLine in range (6, 24) :
        self.lblFxsLines[disableLine].setEnabled(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with the framework you’re using, but if you want to access an attribute with a procedurally generated name, you’ll likely want to use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr).

Your example would then become:

```
for enable_line in range(1, 6):  # Note: upper bound is exclusive
    getattr(self, 'lblFxsLine%d' % enable_line).setEnabled(1)
for disable_line in range(6, 25):
    getattr(self, 'lblFxsLine%d' % disable_line).setEnabled(0)
```

I would be very surprised, though, if your framework didn’t offer you some way to get a list of these edit boxes.

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track :)