# Define variables in loop where var name depends on iteration

Tags: python

I want to define a number of variables that depends on a certain k. the var name depends on the number of the iteration
for example:

```
for i in range(1,k):
    th(i) = i
```

result should be: th1=1, th2=2, th3=3...

I tried:

```
for i in range(1,k):
    th+str(i) = i
```

didn't work.

any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing variable names with Python for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060090/changing-variable-names-with-python-for-loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual thing to do in such cases is to use a dict, and save the variables as keys in it. Example:

```
variables = {"th%s" % i: i for i in range(1, 100)}
```

This gives output of the form below, and the variables can be accessed via the keys:

```
>>> variables
{'th99': 99, 'th98': 98, ...}
>>> variables["th1"]
1
>>> variables["th10"]
10
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better to use a list instead of multiple variables to store a sequence of values.

```
data = []
for i in range(1, k):
    data.append(i)
```

You can access the items later using indexing:

```
data[index]
```