# Read multiple csv files starting with a string into separate data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have about 500 '.csv' files starting with letter 'T' e.g. 'T50, T51, T52 ..... T550' and there are some other ',csv' files with other random names in the folder. I want to read all csv files starting with "T" and store them in separate dataframes: 't50, t51, t52... etc.'

The code I have written just reads these files into a dataframe

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

for file in glob.glob("T*.csv"):
    print (file)
```

I want to have a different name for each dataframe - preferably, their own file names. How can I achieve this within its 'for loop'?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing variable names with Python for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060090/changing-variable-names-with-python-for-loops)

Comment: you can create a list of files starting with 'T' like this ```filelist = [file for file in os.listdir(folder) if file.startswith('T')]```  Then load them to pandas by looping over the filelist.

Comment: Automatically generating variable names is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010856/8720308)!  Just adapt the ```xrange()``` to ```range()```, depending on your version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally agree with @Comos
But if you still need individual variable names, I adapted the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010856/8720308)!

```
import pandas as pd
import os

folder = '/path/to/my/inputfolder'

filelist = [file for file in os.listdir(folder) if file.startswith('T')]
for file in filelist:
    exec("%s = pd.read_csv('%s')" % (file.split('.')[0], os.path.join(folder,file)))
```

Comment: Thanks ABotros, what if I want to assign the name of the file to the dataframe? Some files also have only alphabets , while most of them have numbers. How can I extract the file name and assign the same to the dataframe it is stored in?

Comment: So you want the file-name as the variable-name of the dataframe? (Thats what the code above should do) Or you want the  file-name as a column-name within the dataframe? Could you specify what you mean? Otherwise, use the solution of @Comos

Comment: Oh yes, want the file-name as the variable-name of the dataframe. However I encountered "NameError", after looking up a bit what I see is, it could be due to "exec" statement. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, there was some bad code in it. I fixed it now and have tried it with my own small example. I forgot to treat the string as an actual string (the ' ' around the %s in the pd.read_csv call). Also I have changed the loop for better readability and adapted the naming system to your requirements.

Comment: This one says, file doesn't exist, when I printed 'filelist', it shows names of all files identified which start with T. Does '%' assign values to respective expressions in 'exec' statement? `exec("%s = pd.read_csv('%s')" % (file.split('.')[0], file))`

Comment: The ```%s``` is a placeholder for a string. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/whats-the-difference-between-s-and-d-in-python-string-formatting) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings) for more explanations on how to use them. In short, the first ```%s``` is filled in with the string contained in ```file.split('.')[0]```, the second ```%s``` is filled in with the string contained in ```file```.  Have you set the folder name? In my working example I just have the files in the same folder as my program, therefore I added ```folder='.'```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196359/discussion-between-abotros-and-shweta24).

Comment: Thank you so much ABotros, this has now worked, the path to the folder while we execute the string was the part where it was failing. It works perfect now!

Answer (score 2):

In additions to ABotros's answer, to read all files in different dataframes, I would recommend adding the files to a dictionary, which will allow you to save dataframes with different names in a loop:

```
filelist = [file for file in os.listdir(folder) if file.startswith('T')]

database = {}
for file in filelist:
    database[file] = pd.read_csv(file)
```